# Existing Database Indentity Column MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using an existing database to create an Project Reporting System. And I want the Primary Key, which is the Project id value of the project table to be automatically created and it is not setting a new value, as I have to input the Id, but I don't want the user to do that. Can anyone help me with this problem please?

Patrick

**Controller**
`        //
        // GET: /Project/Create

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Status = new SelectList(db.pjt_Statuses, "pjt_Status_ID", "StatusName");
        ViewBag.SubCategoryID = new SelectList(db.pjt_SubCategories, "pjt_SubCat_ID", "SubCatName");
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Project/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(pjt_Projects pjt_projects)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            pjt_projects.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
            db.pjt_Projects.Add(pjt_projects);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.Status = new SelectList(db.pjt_Statuses, "pjt_Status_ID", "StatusName", pjt_projects.Status);
        ViewBag.SubCategoryID = new SelectList(db.pjt_SubCategories, "pjt_SubCat_ID", "SubCatName", pjt_projects.SubCategoryID);
        return View(pjt_projects);
    }`
```

**Database Table Script**

```
`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[pjt_Projects](
[Pjt_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ProjectName] [nchar](100) NULL,
[Status] [int] NULL,
[Start_Date] [date] NULL,
[Estimated_End_Date] [date] NULL,
[Documents] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Notes] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Budget] [smallmoney] NULL,
[Current_Spending] [smallmoney] NULL,
[ProjectOwner] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Active] [bit] NULL,
[Actual_End_date] [date] NULL,
[CreationDate] [date] NULL,
[CreatedByEmpNo] [nchar](10) NULL,
[UpdateDate] [date] NULL,
[UpdatedByEmpNo] [nchar](10) NULL,
[SubCategoryID] [int] NULL,`


**Generate Context Db Code**
    public int Pjt_Id { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Status { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Start_Date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Estimated_End_Date { get; set; }
    public string Documents { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Budget { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Current_Spending { get; set; }
    public string ProjectOwner { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Active { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Actual_End_date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedByEmpNo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedByEmpNo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SubCategoryID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Going to need some sample code or else we have no idea what you are really asking.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin What do you want me to show...

Comment: Show us what you have so far, that would be a good starting point.

Comment: @Dimitar Dimitrov database script, controller and Database Generate class code is up. Anything else?

Comment: All you have to do is exclude the ID field from the view.  What's the problem?

Comment: Does Pjt_Id have a primary key constraint setup in the DB?

Comment: @dbaseman Tried that and it wont create/input the information into the database.

Comment: @Andrew Lewis Yup, I inputted a test through Sql Server and the information added in successfully along with placing an id, its within MVC I am getting the problem.

Comment: Sorry, @dbaseman, you are right, i setted the value for the id to be hidden within the view. Should have known better to delete it from the view.

Cheers,
Patrick Melia.

One other q, those anyone know how to get a file(*.doc, *.pdf) uploaded to sharepoint.

Comment: @PatrickMelia, that's an entirely separate question. Post it, and SO will answer; the comments are not the place for it.

Comment: Ok just asking, sorry @anaximander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply exclude the ID field from the Razor view.  (Self explanatory unless you're using `EditorForModel`, in which case you'd need to modify the `Display` annotation for the ID field, so that the Razor engine knows to exclude it from the view.)

Once excluded, its value will not get posted back to the server.  That way it will get the default value when created in the MVC controller; and the database will auto-generate the new ID.